# Removing the rotation data from an Instance in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

[image: node groups which performs the alignment]

Hi there, I am trying to remove this rotation data of a selected Instance to bring it back to 0deg,0deg,0deg. What can I do for that with the Rotate Instances node?

I am doing this to re-align it with something else, because it's current rotation hinders what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use this setup, I don't think it's correct way of doing it, but it will cancel instances rotation

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, and BTW that was really complicated. 
I finally found an answer, I had posted it if you wanna check out

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, you have to apply the negative values in the Opposite order, ie, ZYX
[image: Node showing how to apply the opposite rotation]